# AWS EC2 Reverse DNS (PTR) Failing

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

Have searched everywhere, can't find answer.

I have the domain mydomain.com. The root and www records point to my main server, which runs my website.

I am now using a separate AWS ec2 instance to set up an email server for my domain. This is running on the subdomain *mail*.

My dns looks like this:

```
A @ webserverip
A www webserverip
A mail ec2ip
```

To prevent my server from getting flagged for spam, I submitted the amazon reverse dns form here: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

I gave them the ip of my ec2 mail server, and put "mail.mydomain.com" in the "Reverse DNS Record for EIP 1" box.

However, I keep receiving emails back from them saying:

> When attempting to map the reverse DNS entry, we notice that this is failing because the PTR record doesn't match the A record for that domain.
>
> We currently require the forward A record to match the PTR record for all reverse DNS entries.

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. The "mail" subdomain has an A record pointing to my ec2 server ip. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

(I am using cloudflare for my dns if this makes any difference)

Comment: Maybe mention your domain so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to configure the DNS for your EC2 dedicated mail server on AWS:

**STEPS**

1. Add two **A** host records for `pop.mydomain.com` and
   `smtp.mydomain.com` that point to your elastic IP and assign your
   **MX** record to the `smtp.mydomain.com` host.
2. Add a **CNAME** record (not **A** host record) for `mail.mydomain.com` that points to the DNS entry assigned by AWS (e.g., `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.REGION.compute.amazonaws.com`).
3. Submit your rDNS request for `smtp.mydomain.com` mapping to your EIP.
4. Don't forget to add the SPF **TXT** record for your mail server. For example, *v=spf1 mx a*

Once you're done with this setup, you should have a proper mail server configuration in terms of DNS that would pass SMTP tests and avoids being flagged as spam.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. I made the changes and resubmitted the form, I will let you know if it worked!

Comment: @KhalidT. this doesn't make sense. This is neither required by AWS nor is it a valid configuration at all. The value of a PTR record must point to an A record, not a CNAME record pointing to an A record. *"the value of a PTR record must not be an alias"* -- [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-10](RFC-2181 Sec 10.2).  If `mail.example.com` is a CNAME, then it is an alias, in the sense intended in the RFC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: You are absolutely right. I guess I wasn't clear in my answer above. I forgot to mention the reverse DNS request to AWS must include the MX record host `smtp.mydomain.com`, not `mail.mydomain.com`. I have re-written the answer.